# How to get the size of an ArrayList within an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, size

I need to get the size of each inner `ArrayList` (using a for loop) with the `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`s defined:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> manip = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

I know I can get the size of the outer `ArrayList` with `manip.size()`, but how can I get the size of the inner `ArrayList`?

Comment: `int[] sizes = manip.stream().mapToInt(ArrayList::size).toArray();`

Comment: If you know you can get the size by calling `size()` and you know you can loop through the outer list to get the inner lists, what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the code below:

```
for (ArrayList<String> child:manip) { 
   System.out.println(child.size());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (ArrayList<String> a:manip) {
    System.out.println(a.size);
}
```

should solve your problem. You can do whatever you want inside the loop, such as assigning to variables, but that is the basic structure.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through outer ArrayList, each item is an ArrayList by itself, so basically you can get it's size just by calling .size().

```
for (ArrayList<String> temp : manip) {
  System.out.println(temp.size());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To print out the size of each list inside `manip`:

```
manip.stream().mapToInt(List::size).forEach(System.out::println);
```

To print out the size of a list at `X` position:

```
System.out.println(manip.get(X).size());
```